# Parsing html from external url in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, parsing

I want to make a javascript application able to parse an html of an external URL.
The URL will be in a different domain than my server. My idea is to get the html
of the external URL I want to parse as a String, and then parsing it (I have to check 
only the content of one tag in the head of html)

1)How can I get as a String the html of an external URL in Javascript?
2)How can I parse such retrieved String?

I have red about jquery and ajax; It seems that Ajax will not allow me to do it because doesn't allow cross-domain operations. So maybe jquery can retrieve the html and parse it.. other similar post in this forum were too complicated and didn't come rightly to my point.

thanks everybody for the help

Comment: Better use web services ...!!!

Comment: This is a common question here in StackOverflow. Please use the search. It's usually involves "Cross-domain" so better search for that. As for parsing, jQuery can handle that.

Comment: jQuery wont help you bypass JavaScript security restrictions.. But you can do this on the server side..

Comment: I forgot to say that I do use the IDE Eclipse.

Comment: Thanks everybody. I already did it by the server side and It works, but my teacher said that now I have to make the client pushing to do it. The application parses a random ID facebook page and checks if it exists or not or not accessible. Due to some facebook restrictions, my teacher wants I do it also by client side...

Comment: so JQUERY can do that or not? What about JSON?